# $(document).on('click', sel,.. doesn't work on ipad, but $(sel).on('click' does

Tags: jquery, ipad

having this html:

```
<div class="area">
    <div class="msg">click here</div>
</div>
```

doing this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.area', function(){ alert('hi'); });
```

will not work on the ipad (safari, and chrome),
it works on windows and android browsers

however, this code:

```
$('.area').on('click', function(){ alert('hi'); });
```

will work on the ipad as well.

is this a bug or feature ?

Comment: maybe it's due to the jquery version you are using? I'm not sure why $(document).on('click'...) would not work.

Comment: using `jquery 3.3.1`

Comment: i'd say according to Apple its a feature :) but to me it does sound like a bug.